# Loading CreateJS with RequrieJS. "shim" option dosen't work

Tags: javascript, requirejs, createjs

In my requireJS config i have

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "js",
    paths: {
        react: "libs/react/" + (DEBUG ? "react" : "react.min"),
        domready: "libs/require/plugins/domready.min",
        superagent: "libs/superagent/superagent.min",
        createjs: "libs/createjs/createjs.min" //Combined createJS lib

    },
    shim: {
        createjs: { exports: "createjs" }
    },
    waitSeconds: 0
});
```

Then I want to require createJS as dependency of my module

```
define(
    [
        "react",
        "createjs",
        "config",
        "common"
    ],
    function(React, CreateJS, Config, Common) {
        console.log(CreateJS); //Didn't work. Returning empty require module object
        console.log(createjs); //Proper CreateJS object
    }
);
```

CreateJS is not actual representation of global variable createjs. shim option does nothing. Result without shim the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fiddling around, I found that in combined version of createjs, there is definition of [JSON3 module](https://github.com/CreateJS/Combined/blob/master/builds/createjs-2015.05.21.combined.js#L13677). This module you've got as dependency, not full createjs.
To use requirejs and createjs, see [this example](https://github.com/CreateJS/EaselJS/wiki/Using-easeljs-and-tweenjs-with-requirejs)
You will need to require easel, tween and other modules separately.